# Understanding why the extends arrow points in the opposite direction

Tags: uml, computer-science, class-diagram

In class diagrams I typically see something like ClassA extends ClassB where the arrow head points to ClassA. Example, [here](https://github.com/cardin/SeiON/wiki/Understanding-SeiON). This has always confused me. Why is the arrow head not pointing to ClassB?

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

UML is simply used wrong in those diagrams. The arrow head must be a triangle (not an open one) it must point into the other direction and it is called realizes not implements. So if I did not entirely misinterpret the diagrams the author (of the diagram or of the software which created them) simply did not know how to use UML correctly.

In [this diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams/class-interface-realization.png) (just found by googling) you can see a correct visualization of a class "SearchService" realizing (implementing) the interface "SiteSearch".

[image: Interface Realization]

In [the next diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams/class-generalizaion-separate.png) several classes are generalized by (specialize, extend) the class "Account".

[image: Generalization]

On [this site](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-reference.html) you can get an overview (looks correct on the first glance). If you want to be sure you should look into [the specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML) (find pdf download there).

Comment: Why is it called it realizing and generalizing?

Comment: The authors of UML tried to use more general terms. And "implements" could be confused with the implementation of a UML model in a programming language. While "extending" is not always true for UML. A more general class can even be restricted by a subclass.

Comment: In the same diagram what is the correct term to describe the relationship Client has with the Visitor and Element objects?

Comment: err, well that's incorrect UML again, I'm afraid. It should be a simple arrowhead like -> not a filled one to depict an association which is navigable in only one direction (also called reference). I should have sought longer for a nice diagram...

Comment: what about relationship of client-element? that arrow is filled and not dashed line

Comment: Well, I should have painted a diagram myself... the filled arrow should be an association, but an association must be denoted by an unclosed (unfilled) arrow like -->.

Comment: I have removed the flawed diagram. Have a look at the "this site" link to see correct visualizations of Associations.

Comment: Dang. did it exactly backwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think the confusion here crops up out of the variations in the way people relate to the subtleties of English grammar.

Some people may be inclined to complete the "inconvenient" but UML-standard token "extend" as "extends", while others will complete it as "extended" when viewing or designing a diagram. Hence the differences in interpretation.